# phonegap plugin onload=false has no effect

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need to prevent that a plugin is being initialised automatically. Therefore I have the following configuration

```
    <feature name="ADBMobile_PhoneGap">
      <param name="onload" value="false" />
      <param name="ios-package" onload="false" value="ADBMobile_PhoneGap" />
    </feature>
```

However, when I run the app the plugin still gets initialised before any javascript calls of that plugin has being executed. Any ideas what I am doing wrongly?

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out?

Comment: Do you mean in general or for the ADB plugin? In general it has no effect if the plugin does not check for this option.